# Combining instructions to automatically RAR a folder in screen, process it, and then clean up?

Tags: linux, ssh, rar

I'm trying to create a single instruction I can execute in a Linux SSH session which will -

1. Create a new screen session.
2. Navigate to that screen session (if it doesn't automatically)
3. Create a split RAR file (asking me for a password) of the folder that the session
   is currently in, to a specified location.
4. Exit the screen session.
5. Kill the screen session.

So far I have this command:

> `screen -S newscreendownloads && screen -r newscreendownloads && rar a -r -p -v500000k ~/files/workfiles.rar *`

The main problem I have is that after creating the screen, it automatically terminates.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049252/how-to-create-a-screen-executing-given-command